# How to record video without any sounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I want to record the video without any background sound or noise in app.
what would be good process to do this as well as how to crop the audio and merge with it recorded video?.

Answer (score 1):

To take Video without audio

```
 //----- SETUP CAPTURE SESSION -----
        //---------------------------------
        NSLog(@"Setting up capture session");
        CaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

        //----- ADD INPUTS -----
        NSLog(@"Adding video input");

        //ADD VIDEO INPUT
        AVCaptureDevice *VideoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if (VideoDevice)
        {
            NSError *error;
            VideoInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:VideoDevice error:&error];
            if (!error)
            {
                if ([CaptureSession canAddInput:VideoInputDevice])
                    [CaptureSession addInput:VideoInputDevice];
                else
                    NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't create video capture device");
        }


    //ADD VIDEO PREVIEW LAYER
        NSLog(@"Adding video preview layer");
        [self setPreviewLayer:[[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:CaptureSession] autorelease]];

        PreviewLayer.orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;     //<<SET ORIENTATION.  You can deliberatly set this wrong to flip the image and may actually need to set it wrong to get the right image

        [[self PreviewLayer] setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

NSLog(@"Adding movie file output");
    MovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

    Float64 TotalSeconds = 60;          //Total seconds
    int32_t preferredTimeScale = 30;    //Frames per second
    CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(TotalSeconds, preferredTimeScale);   //<<SET MAX DURATION
    MovieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;

    MovieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024;                        //<<SET MIN FREE SPACE IN BYTES FOR RECORDING TO CONTINUE ON A VOLUME

    if ([CaptureSession canAddOutput:MovieFileOutput])
        [CaptureSession addOutput:MovieFileOutput];

    //SET THE CONNECTION PROPERTIES (output properties)
    [self CameraSetOutputProperties];           //(We call a method as it also has to be done after changing camera)



    //----- SET THE IMAGE QUALITY / RESOLUTION -----
    //Options:
    //  AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh - Highest recording quality (varies per device)
    //  AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium - Suitable for WiFi sharing (actual values may change)
    //  AVCaptureSessionPresetLow - Suitable for 3G sharing (actual values may change)
    //  AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 - 640x480 VGA (check its supported before setting it)
    //  AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 - 1280x720 720p HD (check its supported before setting it)
    //  AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto - Full photo resolution (not supported for video output)
    NSLog(@"Setting image quality");
    [CaptureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
    if ([CaptureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480])     //Check size based configs are supported before setting them
        [CaptureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];



    //----- DISPLAY THE PREVIEW LAYER -----
    //Display it full screen under out view controller existing controls
    NSLog(@"Display the preview layer");
    CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
    [PreviewLayer setBounds:layerRect];
    [PreviewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                                                  CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
    //[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[[self CaptureManager] previewLayer]];
    //We use this instead so it goes on a layer behind our UI controls (avoids us having to manually bring each control to the front):
    UIView *CameraView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    [[self view] addSubview:CameraView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:CameraView];

    [[CameraView layer] addSublayer:PreviewLayer];


    //----- START THE CAPTURE SESSION RUNNING -----
    [CaptureSession startRunning];
```

To merge an audio

```
 //Create AVMutableComposition Object which will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack or we can say it will hold our video and audio files.
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    //Now first load your audio file using AVURLAsset. Make sure you give the correct path of your videos.
    NSURL *audio_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Asteroid_Sound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AVURLAsset  *audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_url options:nil];
    CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);

    //Now we are creating the first AVMutableCompositionTrack containing our audio and add it to our AVMutableComposition object.
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    //Now we will load video file.
    NSURL *video_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Asteroid_Video" ofType:@"m4v"]];
    AVURLAsset  *videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_url options:nil];
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,audioAsset.duration);

    //Now we are creating the second AVMutableCompositionTrack containing our video and add it to our AVMutableComposition object.
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    //decide the path where you want to store the final video created with audio and video merge.
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *outputFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FinalVideo.mov"]];
    NSURL *outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

    //Now create an AVAssetExportSession object that will save your final video at specified path.
    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    _assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
    _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self exportDidFinish:_assetExport];
         });
     }
     ];
}
```

Comment: This is not suitable code Aju still noise and audio in recording are coming . I think you have just copy and paste the code from- http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2 . This is also not helpful

Comment: I have resolved my issue and this is final code to mute background voice or noise -   AVCaptureConnection* audioConnection = [MovieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

    if(audioConnection)
    {
        audioConnection.enabled=NO;
    }

Answer (score 0):

AVCapturesession lets you record video without sound and then use AVMutableComposition for inserting separate track.